# Generate a random number for each row dependent on another column Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

Let it be the following Dataframe of pandas in Python.

| Column_1 | Column_2 | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UDKA | 1234 | 5 |
| MAKU | 1544 | 5 |
| POKA | 5434 | 2 |
| UJFK | 9104 | 3 |

I want to generate a random number column that generates for each row a random number between 1 and its value in the Number column `df['Random'] = rand(1, x.Number)`. Example result:

| Column_1 | Column_2 | Number | Random |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UDKA | 1234 | 5 | 4 |
| MAKU | 1544 | 5 | 2 |
| POKA | 5434 | 2 | 1 |
| UJFK | 9104 | 3 | 2 |

Obviously Random cannot be strictly greater than Number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a random [0,1) float, then multiply by the upper bound and add 1:

```
import numpy as np

df['random'] = (df['Number'].mul(np.random.random(size=len(df))).astype(int)
                .add(1)
               )
print(df)
```

output:

```
  Column_1  Column_2  Number  random
0     UDKA      1234       5       3
1     MAKU      1544       5       1
2     POKA      5434       2       2
3     UJFK      9104       3       1
```

*edit: `clip` is actually not needed as `random` generates a [0,1) number.*

Comment: @mozway..How you are so fast!! +1